# Cygwin: Can I automatically change wa-foo-go to smart_wa_foo_go by only typing wa-foo-go?

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, bash-scripting

When I type:

```
$ ./somescript.sh <file-script-test> wa-foo-go`
```

I want it to change that automatically so that it thinks I typed:

```
$ ./somescript.sh <file-script-test> smart_wa_foo_go
```

Or others like `bk-bar-rr` turning into `smart_bk_bar_rr`

All are in the same format of `xx-xxx-xx` and all need the `smart_xx_xxx_xx` "conversion"

I just don't want to type it all out every time I run this `somescript.sh`

Answer (score 2):

```
# define a wrapper:
$ myfun() { ./somescript.sh "$1" "smart_${2//-/_}"; }

# call it
$ myfun file-script-test wa-foo-go
```

Answer (score 1):

In the script you could modify the argument name

```
filename="smart_"$1
... operate on $filename
```